# R Markdown horizontal rule only works under headings, nowhere else, why?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

In R Markdown I can type the following code, knitr it to HTML, and a horizontal rule is created underneath the heading, but not underneath the text. If I paste the same code into this StackOverflow pane I'm typing into right now there are horizontal rules under both the heading and the text. Why does R Markdown leave out the second horizontal rule?

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
---

# Heading
***

Text
***
```

Comment: A very similar version of this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466504/adding-horizontal-rule-to-html-rmarkdown-doc-hides-sections-of-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make an extra line break

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
---

# Heading
***

Text

***
```